# Relative path in dev incorrectly translated in staging

Tags: javascript, reactjs, svg, path

I have this situation in React that in development I point to a logo in footer with a relative path wchich is:

```
import logo from "../../public/assets/images/logo-white.svg";
```

And this path is not working on the staging server, after debugging i found out that the assets part is missing in the path, in devtools the path is:

```
/images/logo-white.svg?49346bf607b2345c88562df1dde21b97
```

when I add the assets part before slash it works, I cannot use absolute path in component and I don't know what can I do to fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use it like this for production:
`process.env.PUBLIC_URL + '/images/logo-white.svg'`

You can find the detailed documentation on when and how to use the [public folder in the React docs](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/using-the-public-folder/)